# Обязательные POST параметры Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Для задания обязательных `GET` параметров, я в параметрах `action` прописываю:

```
public function actionTest(int $required_param, int $required_param_2){
```

Теперь при попытке запроса страницы `test` без указания `required_param` и `required_param_2`, `Yii` выдаст ошибку: "Отсутствуют обязательные параметры".

Вопрос - как сделать обязательные `POST` параметры?
Например, в `verbs` разрешил только метод `POST`:

```
'verbs' => [
        'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
        'actions' => [
            'test' => ['POST'],
        ],
    ],
```

Теперь запросил эту страницу методом `POST`, передав параметры `required_param`, `required_param_2` уже в теле запроса (т.е. раньше было `$_GET['required_param']`, сейчас стало `$_POST['required_param']`).

Но `Yii` по-прежнему ожидает эти параметры как `GET`, и выдает ошибку:
"Отсутствуют обязательные параметры".

Как решить мою проблему и указать обязательные `POST` параметры?

Comment: Если параметры оставить в экше, то он и будет ругаться на отсутсвие оных, т.к они там только для GET

Answer (score 0):

Нативного способа передать post параметры в экшн у Yii2 нет. Туда передаются только GET  параметры. Обойти можно переопределив метод у контроллера:

```
public function runAction($id, 
    $params=array()){
    $params = array_merge($_POST, $params);
    parent::runAction($id, $params);
}
```

Ещё может помочь такой метод:

```
public function bindActionParams($action, $params) {
    return array_merge($params, Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams());
}
```